# Is there a JS/jQuery Fully Recursive child node count function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, count, children

Folks,

Let's say that I have the following situation:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div>
        <span>
             <ul>
                 <div> </div>
                 <div> </div>
             </ul>
         </span>
     </div>
  </div>
```

How would I find the total number of elements inside div.outer? Something like $('div.outer').children().size() or length returns 1 (I'm looking, in this case, for 5) is there a shortcut or function to find the total element count using js/jQuery or should I write a function just for this issue? TIA.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`var totalDescendants = $('div.outer *').length;`

and done.

---

`var totalDescendants = $('div.outer').find('*').length;`

would also work.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the prompt answer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple (and likely faster than jQuery) JavaScript alternative would be

```
var el = document.getElementById("foo");
var descendantElementCount = el.getElementsByTagName("*").length;
```

This does assume you've given the element an id. You could use jQuery to get all the elements with class `outer`, if this is important:

```
var descendantElementCount = 0;
$('div.outer').each(function() {
    descendantElementCount += this.getElementsByTagName("*").length;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery recursive child node count function:

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var totalChildren=jQuery("*","div.outer").length;
});`